# How to convert UTM (easting,northing) to Geographic (lat,long) in degree decimal using geotools

Tags: geotools

I want to convert easting, northing values in meters of UTM to lat,long of geographic coordinate system using geotools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

follow the instructions in the CRS Tutorial ([http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial
/geometry/geometrycrs.html](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/geometry/geometrycrs.html))

Comment: I hate to tl;dr this, but I looked all the page you liked to and haven't found the answer to the OP. Could you update the link so it includes the anchor for the relevant section, please?

Comment: you need to follow all the steps

Comment: @iant That Tutorial seems to be about designing a Swing application and has no references to UTM. Could you extract the core API calls for GeoTools-15 (which is the current latest, per your use of a non-static URL) and edit your answer to include code?

Answer (score 0):

to converting from utm to lat lon, you maybe want to look this code for python implementation [UTM to LatLon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/344083/430408)

and another source [LatLongUTMconversion.py](http://mahi.ucsd.edu/class233/data/Basic/LatLongUTMconversion.py)

and the last thing for [LatLon to DMS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2056789/430408):

i hope it helps you

Comment: i am unable to decode this line in java ------------------ longitude = ((zone > 0) and (6 * zone - 183.0) or 3.0) - _a3. Can u help me doing so.